# Fsharp wcf type provider reuse data contracts

Tags: wcf, f#, f#-3.0

I am using the fsharp wsdl type provider to generate client side classes to consume wcf services. However, I am not able to reuse the same data contracts between different services that on the server side use the same data contracts.

I read some material discussing this for C# wcf projects using the svcutil, but how can this be accomplished while using the wsdl type provider mechanism?

This is an example of my problem:

So the following data object cannot be shared (as it is) by two different services like:

```ml
[<DataContract>]
type QuantityUnit () =
    [<DataMember>] member val Quantity = 0. with get, set
    [<DataMember>] member val Unit = "" with get, set
```

And this data object is used by:

```ml
[<ServiceContract>]
type IQuantityUnitService =
    inherit IDataProviderServiceContract

    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract member NewQuantityUnit: quantity: float * unit: string -> QuantityUnit
```

And

```ml
[<ServiceContract>]
type ICalculationService =
    inherit IDataProviderServiceContract

    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract member CalculateQuantityUnit: quantity: QuantityUnit -> QuantityUnit
```

But the generated class QuantityUnit for both services, has to generated for each service and cannot be passed from one service to the next service.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that this question received no response and that in the meantime I couldn't come up with a workaround, I think it is save to assume that in fact, reuse of types between Wcf services implemented in Fsharp is not possible.
Therefore, and for other reasons I switched to ServiceStack. An investment most worthwhile. It is much simpler, faster and reuse is a non issue as you can directly reference and reuse your data contracts.